# Como comparar dados criptografados com crypt

Tags: php, sql

Olá, estou tentando aprender como criptografar dados. Criei um código `php` para salvar os dados no banco `mySQL` e outro para comparar os dados de entrada do usuário com o banco.

Para criptografar usei a função `crypt()`. O problema é que quando faço a comparação é gerado uma nova senha criptografada que não corresponde com a do banco, como resolver isso? A minha versão do php é `5.3.4`.

```
<?php

     //cadastramento
     $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    //criptografar senha
    $cript_senha =  crypt($senha);

    $sql = "SELECT senha FROM administrador";

    //cadastrar administrador   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO administrador (senha)       
    VALUES ('$cript_senha')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

         print "Registrado com sucesso!";

    } else {

        print "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

?>
```

---

```
<?php
    //entrada do usuário 
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    $sql = "SELECT  senha FROM administrador";

    //quando faço a comparação não da certo, 
    //pois é gerada uma nova      
    //senha  que   não confere com a do banco

    if ((crypt($senha, $row["senha"])) == $row["senha"]) {

        print "Senhas idênticas";


    } else {

         print "Senhas diferentes ";
    } 

?>
```

Comment: De acordo com a documentação, o segundo parametros é um salt, e você está passando a senha ja do banco. remova o `$row["senha"]` do if e veja se funcione.

Comment: Der um `var_dump` no array `$rows` se realmente ele tiver o índice `senha` verifique no seu banco de dados se o tamanho da coluna `senha` tem um tamanho grande o suficiente para armazenar a senha criptografada, recomendo deixar a coluna com um `varchar(255)`. Pois o banco pode estrar `truncando` (quebrando) o valor e por isso a validação não confere.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe o `if` dele está correto, é assim mesmo a validação, no cado o `salt` seria a senha criptografada.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer a comparação com a senha criptografada você precisa ter duas senha já criptografadas ou criptografá-las em tempo de execução, pelo que deu de notar você está comparando uma criptografada com uma senha sem estar criptografada oque realmente nunca ira ser igual.

Comment: Usei o primeiro exemplo daqui http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.crypt.php

Comment: Você deveria utilizar uma combinação de string fixa como segundo parâmetro da função cript pois se utilizar alguma que mude ele ira criptografar diferente uma mesma senha, oque iria causar problemas na sua comparação. Exemplo: 
&Salt = '12318484'
crypt ( string $senha [, string $salt ] ) Desta forma a base da criptografia sempre sera a mesma, evitando problemas na comparação.

Comment: @AntonioRaichaski nesse caso o `salt` deve ter o valor do dado criptografado, sempre usei assim e nunca tive problema. A coluna dele do `MySQL` deve estar definida com um tamanho pequena e acabou truncando a senha criptografada.

Comment: Mas o salt seria a base que ele irá utilizar para criptografar o valor informado, imagino que não seria correto informar o campo já criptografado como salt, mas se funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Comparação correta

```
if ((crypt($senha)) == $row["senha"]) {
    // Senhas iguais
}
```

Acredito que o código correto na comparação seja esse, e não `crypt($senha, $row["senha"])` conforme colocado na pergunta, sendo assim acho que da forma como coloquei funcione.

Answer (score 1):

O erro provavelmente não está na verificação e sim no banco de dados, a coluna onde a `senha` deve ser armazenada provavelmente está definida com um comprimento `pequeno` assim `truncando` a criptografia gerada. Montei um pequeno exemplo:

**SQL:**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `administrador`;
USE DATABASE `administrador`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `administrador` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `senha` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Olhe que o campo de senha está definido com comprimento de até `255` caracteres (suficiente para não truncar mais).

**Index:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="php.php?action=register">
            Senha: <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="php.php?action=login">
            Senha: <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**php.php: (cadastra e valida)**

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

//cadastramento
if($action == "register") {
    @$senha = $_POST["senha"];

    //criptografar senha
    $cript_senha =  crypt($senha);

    $sql = "SELECT senha FROM administrador";

    //cadastrar administrador   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO administrador (senha)   VALUES ('$cript_senha')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        //se ocorrer tudo certo volta para o index para ser feito login
        header("location:index.php?info=ok");

    } else {

       print "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else if($action == "login") {
    //entrada do usuário 
    @$senha = $_POST["senha"];

    $sql = "SELECT  senha FROM administrador";
    //executa minha sql e pega o resultado em $row
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    var_dump($row); //mostra $row

    if ((crypt($senha, $row["senha"])) == $row["senha"]) {
        print "Senhas idênticas"; // agora ele autenticará
    } else {

         print "Senhas diferentes ";
    } 
}
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema!